# Cap SQL Table At a Limit

Tags: sql

I have the following table (first 3 columns) and I want to write some sql code to produce the 4th column (capped amount). The definition of the 4th column is that it is

1. Equal to purchase amount when aggregate is <= 40
2. Equal to purchase amount - (aggregate amount - 40) in the first instance where Capped Amount is > 40
3. 0 in every instance there after

Here is an example of my desired column. The table is ordered by date chronologically.

```
Client_ID | Purchase Amount | Aggregate Amount | Date |  Capped Amount  
1               $23                  $23       1/1/2022      $23    
1               $16                  $39       1/2/2022      $16  
1               $14                  $53       1/3/2022      $1  
1               $9                   $62       1/4/2022      $0  
2               $15                  $15       2/3/2022      $15  
2               $16                  $31       2/4/2022      $16   
2               $1                   $32       2/5/2022      $1  
2               $100                 $132      2/6/2022      $8  
2               $14                  $146      2/7/2022      $0
```

Comment: in number 2 do you mean when aggregate amount us over 40? also, what do you mean by first? what determines the order?

Comment: You  need to have a column that indicates order

Comment: Hi, sorry, I meant to assume that the table is ordered by date. Purchase amounts are chronological. I didn't add this because I was struggling to format the table.

Comment: capped amount doesn't get above $40. are you talking about a running sum? if so, is it between all users?

Comment: Add the date column too. It's needed.

Comment: @jarlh added a date column